# Why is 2010/08/15 matching to M/d/yy?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have an array of valid date formats I want to detect in a some text a user enters:

```
public static final DateFormat[] DATE_FORMATS = {
    new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("M.d.yy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("M-d-yy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("M.d.yyyy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("M-d-yyyy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("M.dd.yy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("M-dd-yy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("M.dd.yyyy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("M-dd-yyyy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("MM/d/yy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("MM.d.yy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("MM-d-yy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("MM/d/yyyy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("MM.d.yyyy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("MM-d-yyyy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yyyy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
};
```

Dates are detected through the code below. this.searchTokens is an array of each search term from the user's entered text.

```
    List<Date> datesFound = new ArrayList<Date>();

    for (String token : this.searchTokens) {

        Date date;

        for (DateFormat dateFormat : DateHelper.DATE_FORMATS) {
            try {
                // Attempt to parse this token as a date.
                date = (Date) dateFormat.parse(token);
                datesFound.add(date);
                break;
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

This code validates and adds the correct dates to my List object for any date except dates formatted like so:

- yyyy/MM/dd
- yyyy.MM.dd
- yyyy-MM-dd

In one of my unit tests, the dates 2010/08/15 and 2011/08/15 match to M/d/yy the first time through the loop and become Date objects with the values Jun 8, 2182 and Jul 8, 2182, respectively. Why would the first SimpleDateFormat in DATE_FORMATS accept a match like this? The number of digits don't even match up... Is there a better way I should go about detecting these dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `.setLenient(false)` on the `SimpleDateFormat` object you created.

I think M and MM will still both match 1 or 2 digits though. I think you would have to check that yourself (with a regex) if that's not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.  Using .setLenient(false) by itself did not fix the problem.

```
for(int i=0; i < PropDateFormats.length; i++)
{
    try
    {   
    ParsePosition p = new ParsePosition(0);
    PropDateFormats[i].setLenient(false);
        PropagationDate = PropDateFormats[i].parse(_date,p);
    if(p.getIndex() < _date.length())
    {
        log.trace("setPropagationDate.parse("+_date+") failed. Index=["+i+"[ as"+PropagationDate);
    throw new ParseException(_date, p.getIndex());
     }
         log.trace("setPropagationDate.parse("+_date+") passed. Index=["+i+"[  as"+PropagationDate);
          break;
     }
```